# Failed to retrieve spesific data from SQLite Database (Android)

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, authentication

Hi guys i'm kinda new in Java and SQLite programming, and I have a problem to fetch and retrieve specific data from SQLite database,,
I want to create a login program, and user will input username and password (LoginScreen.java), it will check the existing data in database (database.java), and if exists, it will return true to LoginScreen.java.

After that, LoginScreen.java will check, if true, it will run the SQLViews Intent, if false, it will run the Registration Intent.

And the problem is, my code always return false, even though the data is exists on the database. 
Can you please help me to check and give a correction for my code?

Thank you,

Here are the code :
Database.java

```
package com.thesis.teamizer;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class Database {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "TeamizerDB.db";
public static final String TABLE_MEMBER = "Member";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String MEMBER_USERNAME = "Username";
public static final String MEMBER_PASSWORD = "Password";
public static final String MEMBER_EMAIL = "Email";
public DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

public static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MEMBER + " (" + MEMBER_USERNAME
                + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, " + MEMBER_PASSWORD
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + MEMBER_EMAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MEMBER);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public Database(Context c) {
    ourContext = c;
}

public Database open() throws SQLException {
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {

    ourHelper.close();
}

public boolean createEntry(String username, String password, String email) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(MEMBER_USERNAME, username);
    cv.put(MEMBER_PASSWORD, password);
    cv.put(MEMBER_EMAIL, email);
    ourDatabase.insert(TABLE_MEMBER, null, cv);
    return true;
}

public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] { MEMBER_USERNAME, MEMBER_PASSWORD,
            MEMBER_EMAIL };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(TABLE_MEMBER, columns, null, null, null,
            null, null);

    String result = "";

    int iUsername = c.getColumnIndex(MEMBER_USERNAME);
    int iPassword = c.getColumnIndex(MEMBER_PASSWORD);
    int iEmail = c.getColumnIndex(MEMBER_EMAIL);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {

        result = result + c.getString(iUsername) + " "
                + c.getString(iPassword) + " " + c.getString(iEmail) + "\n";

    }

    return result;
}

public Boolean getName(String l) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String Query = "SELECT USERNAME FROM " + TABLE_MEMBER + " WHERE "
            + MEMBER_USERNAME + " =?";
    Cursor mCursor = ourDatabase.rawQuery(Query, new String[] { l });

    boolean hasObject = false;
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        hasObject = false;
        mCursor.close();
    }

    else
        hasObject = true;

    return hasObject;

}

public Boolean getMatched(String username, String password) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    String Query = "SELECT USERNAME FROM " + TABLE_MEMBER + " WHERE "
            + MEMBER_USERNAME + " =? AND " + MEMBER_PASSWORD + " =?";

    Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery(Query, new String[] { username,
            password });
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

LoginScreen.java

```
package com.thesis.teamizer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class LoginScreen extends Activity {

private EditText etUsername;
private EditText etPassword;
private Button bLogin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.login_screen);

    validationUsernameAndPassword();
    ifRegisterButtonClicked();

}

private void validationUsernameAndPassword() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLoginUsername);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLoginPassword);
    bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);

    final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
    final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

    bLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int flag = 0;

            /*
             * if (!isValid(username)) {
             * etUsername.setError("Username must be filled"); flag++; }
             * 
             * if (!isValid(password)) {
             * etPassword.setError("Password must be filled"); flag++; }
             */
            if (flag == 0) {

                Database checkLogin = new Database(LoginScreen.this);
                checkLogin.open();
                Boolean temp = checkLogin.getMatched(username, password);

                // Kalo username n passwordnya benar2 ada di database

                if (temp == true) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            "com.thesis.teamizer.SQLVIEWS");
                    startActivity(intent);

                } // Kalo username n passwordnya salah atau gak ada di
                    // database
                if (temp == false) {
                    Intent i = new Intent("com.thesis.teamizer.REGISSCREEN");
                    startActivity(i);
                }

                checkLogin.close();
            }

        }

        private boolean isValid(String temp) {

            if (temp != null && temp.length() > 6 && !temp.contains(" ")) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

    });
}

private void ifRegisterButtonClicked() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Button bRegis = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);
    bRegis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.thesis.teamizer.REGISSCREEN");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: Although you are repeating your question, I will answer here. I suppose that you are storing previously a set of correct values in order to compare, if that is the case, check that you have information in your database (the insert was correct) and use logs to check if the data matches your rows.

Comment: Yes, i have checked whether the data has exist or not manually with select *, but it stil doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void validationUsernameAndPassword() {
    ...
    final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
    final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

    bLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        ...
```

You are reading the values when the activity is created.
You should do this after the button has been clicked.

Comment: Thank you, it really helps. Never thought that the structure and placement is really important..